# Determine if there is an overloaded function defined for a parameter of a specific type

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a simple serialization framework that defines specializations of Read and Write template functions for various types including arithmetic, my classes, and std containers like vector, array, map, etc..., so it is possible to do

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "a1", "b123", "c12345" };
Read(stream, v);
Write(stream, v);
```

or

```
std::map<int, MyClass> m;
Read(stream, m);
Write(stream, m);
```

, for example.

I am looking for a way to determine at compile time is a type serializable or not by implementing something like this:

```
template <class T>
constexpr bool is_serializable()
{
    if (Read<T> and Write<T> are defined) 
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

or probably something else.

Is it possible?

The declarations of Read and Write:

```
    template <typename T>
    void Read(InputStream & s, T & val);

    template <typename T>
    void Write(OutputStream & s, T val);
```

theoretically I can define is_serializable for every type I need in addition to Read and Write, but this requires more typing and makes the code more complicated probably, so having is_serializable defined automatically is more elegant way.

It also can be some Serializer template class with Read and Write functions as members. In this case I need to know if there is a specialization of Serializer for a specific type. For example, I can do [something like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XBlao5Yg6kyZVvV8) with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::void_t` and SFINAE to achieve that. The documentation of `std::void_t` in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) is great.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

void Read(std::istream &,double &) {}
void Write(std::ostream &,double) {}

template <typename T,typename= void>
struct is_serializable_t: std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_serializable_t<T,std::void_t<
    decltype(Read(std::declval<std::istream &>(),std::declval<T &>())),
    decltype(Write(std::declval<std::ostream &>(),std::declval<T>()))>>:
    std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_serializable = is_serializable_t<T>::value;

static_assert(is_serializable<double>);
static_assert(!is_serializable<int>);
```

Comment: See an example of how the return type of a function is defined, but the function itself does not compile, https://wandbox.org/permlink/9pAFyjTUDyf9Erxp this

Comment: Probably a bit better example (uncomment last Read call) https://wandbox.org/permlink/yuj9T45QnTywO7hE

Comment: In general you answer is great!

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky For your example to compile, you would need to declare `template <class T, class Compare, class Alloc>
int Read(Stream & s, std::set<T *, Compare, Alloc> & coll)`

Comment: I want is_serializable to be false for std::set<T *, Compare, Alloc>, but it is true because the Read function return type is known, but Read function code does not compile.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Ah. OK. Then you may declare it like `int Read(Stream & s, std::set<std::remove_pointer_t<T>, Compare, Alloc> & coll)` to avoid `int *` to be deduced as `T`